# MapView in Main view and Flipside View

Tags: iphone

I have created a MapView in the main view and want to use the same MapView in the flipside view but only expanded in size.  The code draws the mapview in the flipside using the global map instead of the constrained map in the main view.

Any suggestions?

I have tried duplicating the mapping code in the flipside view but the flipside view stops working and freezes the program. One would think that with separate h and m files for the flipside view that the maps would be separate.  I even tried copying the mapview from the main view to the flipside view with no luck.

8 hours of frustration

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me.

Creating separate mapping code in the Flipside view for the h and m files does work.  I suggest creating a separate MapView rather than copying from the main view.

As for me, my mistake was not creating the proper link between with the nib.